# Powershell and Get-ChildItem - why does adding a parameter change the output format?

Tags: windows, powershell, syntax

If I write something like this...

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\my_files | sort LastAccessTime

foreach($file in $files)
{
  Write-host "file is <$file>"
}
```

I get a list of filenames. (filename only, without the path)

But if I make a minor change to exclude some log files that end with numbers...

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\my_files -Exclude *[0-9].log | sort LastAccessTime

foreach($file in $files)
{
  Write-host "file is <$file>"
}
```

Then I get a list of full path and filename.

Why?

I can understand that selected files will change, but why would the format of the output change?

Update - this is powershell version 5.1.19041.3693, which leads to the question, why does windows tell me I'm 'up to date' and why isn't powershell upgrading by default along with all my other updates?

Comment: Is this outdated Powershell 5? I get full paths for both on 7. Any reason you're using that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the - unfortunate - ***situationally varying stringification* of [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) in *Windows PowerShell***.

- This **problem has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** - the latter now *consistently* stringifies instances of these types by their *full paths* (`.FullName` property value).

By referring to `$file` in the context of `"..."`, i.e. an [*expandable (interpolating) string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), the object's `.ToString()` method is called to obtain its string representation, and that's where the problematic behavior manifests:

- *Depending on the specific parameters of the `Get-ChildItem` call*,  the output objects stringify either by their file/directory *name only*, or by their *full path*.
- For details on under what specific circumstances name-only vs. full-path stringification occurs, see the bottom section of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).

---

The **workaround** is to *access the objects' relevant properties explicitly*:

- Use `.FullName` to get the *full path*.
- Use `.Name` if you want only the file / directory *name*.

Note that in order to embed an *expression* such as a *property access* in `"..."`, you need to enclose it in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

To demonstrate in the context of a streamlined reformulation of your code (using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) to process each object, reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), as well as *implicit output*):

```sh
# By using .FullName (or .Name) it doesn't matter whether an 
# -Exclude argument is present or not.
Get-ChildItem -File c:\my_files |
  Sort-Object LastAccessTime |
  ForEach-Object {
    # If you only want the *names*, use $_.Name
    "file is $($_.FullName)"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two experiments:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\my_files  | sort LastAccessTime | gm
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem c:\my_files -Exclude *[0-9].log | sort LastAccessTime | gm
```

Take a close look at the output.  The properties listed are not quite the same,
and appear to correlate with the difference in format of the output.

When PS is asked to print an object that is not printable, it searches for a default way to render it printable.  In this case, the difference in the property list seems to cause PS to find a different way to render a directory object printable.

A full answer would require an explanation of why the property lists are different.  But I hope this sheds a little light on the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the input - but both commands appear to produce the same output? or maybe there's something very subtle somewhere I've missed?

Comment: On my system the description for BaseName is different in the two property lists.